# What is the daily life like as a machine learning PhD student?

Tags: phd, machine-learning

Machine learning has connected with many other displines or research directions, for example it has been combined with materials, fluid mechanics and so many research directions, so what is your daily life if you have to use machine learning methods to complete your PhD topic or your postdoc research?

For example, you can give me a schedule or proportion or your daily life, for example, you have to use half of your workday to decode the ML literatures or algorithms and program, debug, run and test this model, and the other half to do experiments.

Comment: Also, the day in the life of a PhD student is probably quite different from a "researcher" in general.

Comment: This depends on a lot on the country, exact research subject, and knowledge that the PhD student may have in advance. Pretty much anything you can imagine is possible.

Comment: Reading about the different project possibilities in the AIMLAC CDT (http://cdt-aimlac.org/) might be helpful

Comment: ML isn't my field, so I can't provide specific help. But expect to work hard, read a lot, and find some things confusing. Your description, however, is too "methodical".  Finding problems to work on is a big part of any doctorate. Developing methodology. Carrying it out. The "Finding a good problem" can be very challenging.

Comment: I am glad that these senior members are way positive about this. I am probably too young to understand it, so I deleted my previous answers. To OP, the answer to your question depends on your topic. If it's more empirical (most of time, it is), you will spend most of your time on coding, e.g, tuning models and numbers, and relatively less time on learning new algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m a bit puzzled by the negativity of the current answers. From what I know about ML applied to neuroscience (computational neuroscience), and at least some U.S. universities, this isn’t even close to being the case.

It is true that you might help reviewing papers as well as work on grants - both your own, and others to help your PI. At this stage of your career though, it won’t make up anywhere near as much time as postulated in other answers; helping your PI with their grants might not happen at all because it's more common for postdocs instead. Assuming you consider an academic career, it’s also useful training as especially grant writing will make up more of your time in later stages.

As to classes, if there even are any, they will only happen in your first - possibly second - year. Instead, you rotate through labs at the beginning to help find out what you’d like to do (you’re not necessarily locked into computational work upon entering, and might decide to do experimental work instead). If you work interdisciplinary, it’s important to be good not only on the computational side, but also understand the experimental work and related biology, so, again, in any case it’s time well-spent.

When you hit the research stage, if you’re lucky you can hop on a project your adviser has handy for you. If not, you’ll spend some time reading and trying to find your own niche, hopefully working closely with your boss.

When the research begins, you’ll cycle through talking to the experimental groups you work with to decide next steps, and setting up models and running them. Running your models will make up the vast majority of your time then. As needed, you research alternative approaches at the side. When it finally comes to writing your paper, you and your co-authors likely iterate through a fair number of rounds to get it done so everyone is happy.

If you’re the academic type, it’s a rather fascinating life.

Comment: This is factually not correct, at least at my university. But it sounds good and academics love to defend their system so why not upvoted?

Comment: @Fourierflux: If I read your profile and contributions correctly, you are in a machine learning/cs department. This is from a computational (ML) neuroscience perspective (OP asks about interdisciplinary work - other fields using ML), where it is in my experience commonly true in the U.S.

Comment: Yes, I am in ML in a CS/EE department. I would not recommend doing it again. CS/AI topics are an area which can be done wholly without a university. Other areas like device fabrication in EE takes six figures to run top experiments but unless you're running something with a massive number of GPU most things can be run locally or on a cloud service. Maybe my experience is uniquely bad but I don't think so.

Comment: @FourierFlux, I'm still curious. Did you enter ML simply because it was "hot" or did you have a genuine interest in it? There is, IMO, great danger in entering hot areas without knowing what you are getting into. Your comments about everything other than coursework being worthless seems like you are ill prepared. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're confused, I can read arxiv papers on my own, the only meaningful benefit I got out of the PhD program is free courses for things I want to learn about but don't care to independently study. Getting payed 2k/month to work on poorly designed projects you have no interest in and pretend anyone cares about what other people in the research group are doing isn't worth it.

Comment: @FourierFlux, another possibility, of course is that you are another [Will Hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Will_Hunting) for whom most (math, CS, ML...) problems are trivial. Every once in a while I've come across students who have and will shine much brighter than I ever did.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions and comments.

Answer (score -4):

30% you spend working on a pointless poorly constructed project that the PI conned someone into giving them money for, 30% on classes, 30% on meetings nobody cares about or wants to join in and 10% on something you actually want to study.

Comment: Awfully cynical. If your own life is that bad, perhaps you should consider something else.

Comment: Already working on it, I think academia is trash.

Comment: To the OP, here. This is an exceptionally negative view. Don't expect your life to (also) be a worst case.

Comment: From my experience I firmly believe that outside of classes a formal "full time" PhD is an absolute waste of time, both monetarily and intellectually. In the interactions I have had, most Professors neither have particularly great knowledge nor great teaching ability. Additionally most of the "funded" projects are really, really bad. Professors even admit the projects are bad but their main interest is getting more funding so they don't care. It's almost funny how absolutely terrible many universities are, why tax payers continue to pay them is mostly from ignorance I think.

Comment: If you have a different experience as a full time ML PhD student feel free to write it up :).

Comment: @Buffy yeah it’s cynical, but are negative opinions not worth people knowing about? Should we pretend no one has negative experiences in academia?

Comment: @DanRomik, I don't have a problem with negative opinions. But they should be backed up. I'm still curious, of course, about "meetings no one cares about". What sort of meaningless meetings are required of doctoral students?

Comment: Thanks for your opinions and comments.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but two quibbles: the 10% may be optimistic and the “someone” is usually the hapless feds. Best of success to you!

Comment: @FourierFlux， I think your answer is actual and it the real circumanstance in many research groups but I am sorry I can not accept your answer as there is only one choice, I really hope you can share more about your actual exoerience about your phd in this post.